# How to use maven dependency:copy goal?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have 2 artifacts that I'd like to copy from my local repository to a directory in filesystem.

I think dependency:copy does this job. But, it requires an argument artifactItems.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

Can any one help me with using this goal in command line. Unfortunately, maven doesnt show the usage of this goal in command line.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than trying to figure out how to provide an `artifactItem` by command line, I'd configure the command line execution for the dependency plugin.  Do that by specifying `default-cli` as the execution ID.  If you always want to copy the same dependencies, you could hardcode the GAV coords in the artifact item(s).  Or, hardcode any values that remain constant between commands.

To copy different artifacts via command line, use properties as element values and specify the values on the command line.  For example, if configuration for `artifactItem` included `<artifactId>${copy.artifactId}</artifactId>` then

`mvn dependency:copy -Dcopy.artifactId=myArtifact`

would copy myArtifact (example assumes other elements have hardcoded values).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
    <id>default-cli</id> 
    <configuration>
      <artifactItems>
        <artifactItem>
          <!-- hardcode values, or use properties, depending on what you want to do -->
          <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
          <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
          <version>[ version ]</version>
          <type>[ packaging ]</type>
          <outputDirectory>/the/filesystem/dir</outputDirectory>
        </artifactItem>
      </artifactItems>
      <!-- other configurations here -->
    </configuration>
    </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you want to do this from within a Maven project or without one. In case of the former, you can use this:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact='group.id:artifact.id:your.version'
```

In case you define the version of the artifact in your `pom.xml` using properties, you can also have it use that version like this:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dartifact='group.id:artifact.id:${version.property}'
```

Comment: @BakedInhalf The answer assumes that you have maven installed, see here: https://maven.apache.org/index.html

Comment: Eclipse installs maven by default but only as a plugin. I had to make a 2nd install of Maven and add /bin folder to path and so on.. Works now! So now it's just to set up an empty project, download jars, copy jars to your normal project and add them to build path

Comment: There is still the question how to copy two artifacts at the same time at the command line - at least that's how I understand the question and what I'm looking for. I couldn't get a -DartifactItems to work - not sure whether this is at all possible. (I actually wanted to copy 8 at the same time from the command line, and it would reduce the time greatly to do this all at once since the maven startup time does play quite a role here.)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to write *artifactItems* in your pom.xml, you could just use the command: "mvn dependency:copy-dependencies" instead of "mvn dependency:copy".

Comment: what is the difference between dependency:copy-dependencies and mvn dependency:copy? dependency:copy-dependencies doesnt require specifying `<artifactItems>` ? is that the only difference?